# How to Transform floating-action-button into a menu with the related actions

Tags: android, menu, floating-action-button, android-transitions

how to Transform a floating action button (FAB) into a menu, this is my xml layout

```xml
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:datePicker="true"
    app:eventsEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:tint="@color/blanco"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAndroid"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />  
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

I want to Transform the button into a related actions menu
"Transform into a menu with the related actions" as shown on material design:
https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1pdXG8K2i6IR9i5V5raflvDwuADXdUACM%2Ffab-transitions-menu-1.mp4

Comment: Question edit to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native Floating Action Button in android, but there is no code available right now to make it expand to sub-buttons/actions. You can either simulate that effect by adding multiple FABs on your layout, one on top of the other, and when you click the one on top you animate the rest to expand by changing their screen coordinates:

Here is a simple layout for the FABs:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fab4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_download"

                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/download_in_progress"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fab3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_download"

                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/download_in_progress"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_download"

                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/download_in_progress"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/topFab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_download"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:borderWidth="4dp"
                    app:elevation="12dp"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/download_in_progress"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

and then:

```
//to expand the buttons:
topFab.animate().rotationBy(180);
fab2.animate().translationY(-150);
fab3.animate().translationY(-300);
fab4.animate().translationY(-450);

//to collapse them:
topFab.animate().rotationBy(-180);
fab2.animate().translationY(0);
fab3.animate().translationY(0);
fab4.animate().translationY(0);
```

You can also toggle their visibility to get rid of any visual lag when animating them.

Alternatively, you can use a library that does that for you. An example would be [Clans/FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)